# Why does this iOS code permanently tint all UIBarButtonItems?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiappearance

This is very odd.  I just found a rogue line in some 3rd party code:

```
[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

This code seems to cause all my `UIBarButtonItem`s to become permanently tinted gray.  Even programatically tinting the bar button items has no effect.

I commented out the code, the problem went away.

Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: So you mean if you remove that line your `UIBarButtonItem`s look normal?

Comment: Do your UIBarButtonItems hold UITextFields?

Comment: @DarkDust That's right, if I remove that single line my `UIBarButtonItem`s go from a gray tint back to the default application wide tint.

Comment: @MattGibson Not that I'm aware of, although there are a couple with custom views, one of which contains a UISegmentedControl.  The code changes all of them, though, not just that one.

Comment: Try comparing the `[UITextField appearance]` to `[UIBarButtonItem appearance]`. Maybe they got made to be the same object?